# retrieve values from predefined row and a column range

Tags: excel, vba

How to retrieve values from predefined row and a column range (Incremental) to text boxes (Incremental) such that for example value of cell “J4” populate in "textbox1" and its column heading in "Label1" , value of cell “k4” populate in "textbox2" and its column heading in "Label2" and so on ............. value of cell“BG4” populate in "textbox50" and its column heading in "Label50".

I have tried the followings

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim fcolumn As Long
    Dim lcolumn As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("md")
    lastrow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*",         
    SearchOrder:=xlRows,SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    fcolumn = 9
    lcolumn = 50
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        fcolumn = fcolumn + 1
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.TextBox_orderno) Then
            If Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value <> 0 Then
                Me.Label1 = ws.Cells(2, fcolumn)
                Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value
            End If
        If Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value <> 0 Then
            Me.Label2 = ws.Cells(2, fcolumn)
            Me.TextBox1 = Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you explain how your current code does not fit your requirements? We need a specific question from you.

Comment: with this line of codes the values goes into those labels and text boxes
which are specified by me in the code lines. where as the text boxes 
and labels should be populated on incremental basis with loop.

Comment: I'm still not clear about this. For one thing, your two If statements are the same, presumably an error? So, if A2 = textbox1 value, then you say Label1=Cells(2, fcolumn) and TextBox1 = Cells(i, fcolumn). So how do you increment the loop for the controls - is it related to `i`?

Comment: There is a typographical error in the codes please treat line 12 as  ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.TextBox_orderno) .Here A2(A2= order no) gets its value from the user form and i want increment for "fcolumn".

Comment: Please amend the code in your question, not in the comments.

Comment: changes done, please provide the ans if possible

Comment: I've suggested an answer so please provide some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what you are doing, but see if this helps you along. It should at least show you how to dynamically refer to the names of controls which alter only in the number at the end.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fcolumn As Long
Dim lcolumn As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("md")

lastrow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

fcolumn = 9
lcolumn = 50

For i = 2 To lastrow
    fcolumn = fcolumn + 1
    If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(Me.Controls("TextBox" & i - 1)) Then
        If Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value <> 0 Then
            Me.Controls("Label" & i - 1).Value = ws.Cells(2, fcolumn)
            Me.Controls("Textbox" & i - 1).Value = Sheets("md").Cells(i, fcolumn).Value
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```